# Only first occurence of \n is replaced and not the other ones (want to replace all single occurences)

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am new to JavaScript and I was trying to create a tool that copies content from clipboard, replaces all single occurences of `\n` but leaves double new lines as they are, so that:

```
Hello
Hello

Hello
```

would become:

```
Hello Hello

Hello
```

This is  the code I wrote:

```
<script>
    var text="";
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then((clipText) => (text = clipText));
</script>
<script>
  function clipboard(text) {
      var i = 0;
      var result = "";
      while (i < text.length) {
          if (i + 1 < text.length && text.charAt(i) === "\n" && text.charAt(i+1) !== "\n") {
              if (text.charAt(i - 1) !== "\n") {
                  result = result + " ";
                  i += 1;
              } else {
                  result = result + "\n";
                  i += 1;
              }
          } else {
              result = result + text.charAt(i);
              i += 1;
          }
      }
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(result).then();
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      clipboard(text.replace("\r\n", "\n").replace("\r", "\n"))
  }) 
</script>
```

I am not able to understand why it only modifies the first occurance of `\n` and leaves other. I copied the following text:

```
roots and blindly abandon their core, but distinctive, competencies and core values. For
example, it is generally recognized that the reason “New Coke” failed was that it broke
away from the tried-but-true Coca-Cola traditional culture; and the reason Google so far
away from the tried-but-true Coca-Cola traditional culture; and the reason Google so far
```

And it gave back this:

```
roots and blindly abandon their core, but distinctive, competencies and core values. For example, it is generally recognized that the reason “New Coke” failed was that it broke

away from the tried-but-true Coca-Cola traditional culture; and the reason Google so far
 away from the tried-but-true Coca-Cola traditional culture; and the reason Google so far
```

I think the problem is with taking content from clipboard. This almost works. For example, copy the content from [here](https://shivanshverma.ml/text.html) and try opening [this page](https://shivanshverma.ml/clipboard.html). It doesn't work. But the same text works when inserted directly into a variable using the backquote symbols [here](https://shivanshverma.ml/clipboard%20copy.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing with a `.replace()`, using a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead:

```js
const str="This is a string\nwith a\nfew\nline\nfeeds in it.\n\nThe double ones are to be kept,\nbut\nthe single ones\nneed to be replaced\nby blanks!"

console.log(str);

const res=str.replace(/(?<!\n)\n(?!\n)/g," ");
console.log(res);
```

The negative lookbehind and lookahead make sure that the line feed in the center of the regular expression is a single one. Only then will it be replaced by a blank.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works perfectly but I think the problem here is with taking content from the clipboard. For example, copy the content from [here](https://shivanshverma.ml/text.html) and try opening [this page](https://shivanshverma.ml/clipboard.html). It doesn't work. But the same text works when inserted directly into a variable using the backquote symbols [here](https://shivanshverma.ml/clipboard%20copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can capture parts of the string and do the replacement, like:

```
text.replace(/(\w)\n(\w)/g, "$1 $2");
```

Comment: Nearly there, but it will fail with a string like `"... kept,\nbut the single ones..."`, as `,` is not a `\w` character.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948657/only-first-occurence-of-n-is-replaced-and-not-the-other-ones-want-to-replace-a#comment132262887_74948976) comment.